# How could i prove that the sum of a rational and a prime number is always rational?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I know integers are closed under addition, but im not 100% sure on how to prove this? Or is this a false statement as prime numbers are rational aswell?

Any help ?

Comment: $\frac{m}{n}+p=\frac{m+np}{n}$, hence rational.

Answer (score 2):

A prime number is an integer, which is a rational number. The sum of rational numbers is rational.

Answer (score 0):

We know all rational numbers can be expressed as a fraction $\frac{m}{n}$
Also, all prime numbers are integers. Say $p$ is any prime number.
So...
$\frac{m}{n}+p=\frac{m+np}{n}$  which is a fraction so it implies that it is rational.